# Query params in Angular 6 are lost in apache web server

Tags: angular, apache, web, server

This is our first Angular based project. The project renders the UI and is integrated with REST API based on Sprint Boot which is a separate project. The Angular UI is designed to be access with a link as shown below-

http://localhost:4200/productconfig?product=AB23423&user=john

This works as expected with dev environment i.e. its embedded server and development is done!

We are trying to **deploy it in QA with Apache** and the problem occurs. The issue that when it accessed it with following url in apache -

http://localhost:80/productconfig?product=AB23423&user=john

somehow, **it looses all the query params!** W**hen product and user are retrieved, they are null**! And the URL changes to just

http://localhost:80/productconfig **loosing the query param part which never happened in the dev environment i.e. in node server.**

Not sure why this happens!!!
Can any body please point out and give me some pointers/directions towards the solutions?

I added this section after the suggestions so that people trying to help me can see what I am doing -

Here's the Apache and my project structure -

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\productconfig
                          index.html
                          .htaccess
The index.html and .htaccess are inside the productconfig which is my project.
```

The **.htaccess** has the followings and this is based on [https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples][1]

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

The **index.html** looks like this

```
    <!doctype html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>productconfig</title>
         <base href="/productconfig/">

         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
         <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <app-root></app-root>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

I also enabled the following in **httpd.conf** in Apache

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And also, the angular router is configured like this -

```
const routes: Routes = [
     {path: '', redirectTo: '/productconfig', pathMatch: 'full'}, //default path
     {path: 'productconfig',           component: ApplicationHeaderComponent},
];
```

The query parameters are retrieved as follows in the **export class ApplicationHeaderComponent implements OnInit { ... } class**-

```
ngOnInit() {   
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.product = params['product'];
  this.user = params['user'];
});
console.log('Product - ' + this.product + ' and User - ' + this.user);
```

}

However, I still have this issue with the query parameters being lost and not able to retrieve.

Note that as I mentioned, it is working in the dev environment with the angular embedded server!

I appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: You should be checking your rewrite rules in Apache `.htaccess`  or create a new one with right rules

Comment: You need to check (or share here) your QA Apache configuration

Comment: Thanks Joel Joseph and Dusan Bajic for you directions. Based on your suggestion, I have put the **.htaccess** with URL Rewrite rule. I have shown all my works above in my original post. I am still not able to resolve it. Any idea?            Also, Beside Apache, what other webservers would be best to deploy the angular application in QA and PROD? Tomcat? IIS? any preference?